# Including a DLL into Gnu Octave

Tags: matlab, dll, octave

On [this page](http://dde.binghamton.edu/download/camera_fingerprint/) I found an interesting implementation for fingerprinting of digital pictures. It is written in MATLAB, therefore I downloaded *GNU Octave* and tried to run the example.

But I get the error

> 'mdwt' undefined near line 47 column 14
>   error: called from 'NoiseExtract' in file C:/Users/......../CameraFingerprint/Functions\NoiseExtract.m
>   near line 47, column 12

There is a hint on the webpage above:

> Q: Do I need any additional packages or libraries?
>
> A: You need discrete wavelet transforms such as those included in
>   \Filter directory as dll (developed by Markus Lang from Rice
>   University). These .dll run under 32-bit Windows only. You may need to
>   recompile them uder your operating system if different.

So I got the .dll-Files, but how do I use them and the functions inside?